# Bundling Angular Material installed outside node_modules into webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, webpack-2

I need to have my material framework outside my node_modules (I downloaded it from https://github.com/angular/material2), but in this case it fall out from webpack bundling. I am not familiar with webpack, should I conntect Material to it like a third part library? While trying to run my app I get this error. [image]
and this is what says zone.js[image]
In my material/core/style/menu.scss file, where these partials are being imported to, all paths are correct.

EDIT:
In the network tab I see my button-common, layout-common, menu-common and a11y are being seen as xhr, not stylesheets.

This is my tsconfig-build.json, which I think starts material compile process.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../../dist/packages/material",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@angular/cdk": ["../../dist/packages/cdk/public_api"]
    }
},
"files": [
    "public_api.ts",
    "typings.d.ts"
],
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "flatModuleOutFile": "index.js",
    "flatModuleId": "@angular/material",
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true
}
```

}
I am pretty sure my `outDir`, `@angular/cdk` and `flatModuleId` are not correct, but I can't figure out what kind of files should be there.

My Webpack version is 2.6.1.

I'll appreciate any help as I have to idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: "I need to have my material framework outside my node_modules".  Why?  And does it work for you when you add meterial the normal way into node_modules?

Comment: So, you are importing all the partials material css from the `menu.scss` file but they are not included in the final webpack build?

Comment: @StephenWilson it does, but I need to not overwrite, but modify source material files.

Comment: @crash,  yes, it looks for me like whole material folder has been excluded from webpack build.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could update your question with an extract of the `menu.scss` file. Have you tried to import other local `.scss` files to see if they work? Anyway, can't you simply import the standard material library and then use some custom styles to override the default ones?

Comment: @crash it basically only imports these partials:
`@import '../core/style/button-common';
@import '../core/style/layout-common';
@import '../core/style/menu-common';
@import '../core/a11y/a11y';

$mat-menu-vertical-padding: 8px !default;

.mat-menu-panel {
  @include mat-menu-base();
  @include mat-menu-positions();
  max-height: calc(100vh - #{$mat-menu-item-height});
`

Comment: are you sure that relative path `../core/...` is correct? Also, I would call them with their extension `.scss/.css`